# How can I send a UDP packet from my Linux ASUS router?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I have changed the firmware on my router, `unanme -a` yields:

```
Linux RT-AC86U-8458 4.1.27 #2 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 6 18:32:35 EDT 2021 aarch64 ASUSWRT-Merlin
```

I have logged in to ssh to this router, and I am trying to figure out how I can send a UDP packet from this host to a different host on my network.

Here's what I've tried (all failing):

```
echo -n "hello world" | /dev/udp/serverip/15243
# /dev/udp/ doesnt exist

# or

echo -n "hello world" | nc -4u -w0 serverip 15243
# fails with 4 being an invalid option

# or

echo -n "hello world" | nc -u -c serverip 15243
# fails with u being an invalid option
```

How can I send a UDP packet from this host?

Comment: Do you have access to the netcat utility? (Mostly, `nc` will do the trick.)

Comment: If your router is using BusyBox, then it likely has a different version of `nc`.  What is the output of `nc --help`?  I think for UDP your command would look like: `echo -n "hello world" | nc -u -w 1 serverip 15243`

Comment: Based on [the source](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/) the `nc` (netcat) version is from BusyBox and does not support UDP. But it looks like `socat` might be available, which is far more featured and should support UDP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how did you extract this information from the source? I just never know what to look for in a situation like this...

Comment: @birgersp: I've just looked up ASUSWRT-Merlin (given in your output) and there is a link to the source code on github. And there is also [the source for nc.c](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/blob/6b60627c8c9c5c0271e956c914afb5277f81f9c4/release/src/router/busybox/networking/nc.c) and there is socat in src/router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief browsing session into [ASUSWRT-Merlin git repository](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng) tells me ASUSWRT-Merlin uses [Busybox version 1.25.1](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/tree/master/release/src/router/busybox) to to implement `nc`.

[The current upstream version of BusyBox is 1.34.1](https://busybox.net/) as of this writing.

More specifically, it appears ASUSWRT-Merlin uses an old version of BusyBox [configured without the `ENABLE_NC_110_COMPAT` option](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/blob/master/release/src/router/busybox/config_base#L779), which would add UDP support and a few other things to its `nc` command:

```
CONFIG_NC=y
# CONFIG_NC_SERVER is not set
CONFIG_NC_EXTRA=y
# CONFIG_NC_110_COMPAT is not set
```

By changing just the last line in the snippet above to `CONFIG_NC_110_COMPAT=y` and rebuilding either just the BusyBox component or the entire ASUSWRT-Merlin firmware, you would get the functionality you want.

But as Steffen Ullrich commented, ASUSWRT-Merlin also includes [socat](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/tree/master/release/src/router/socat). Try:

```
echo -n "hello world" | socat - UDP:serverip:15243
```

`socat` has multiple modes for using UDP. If using just `UDP:` does not work for you, you could try `UDP-DATAGRAM:` or `UDP-SENDTO:` instead, for example.